# Jersey application running on tomcat result in NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey

I recently tried to move my Jersey application from running on Glassfish 4.1 to run on Tomcat 8.

The application is successfully deployed on tomcat:

```
03-Aug-2015 18:42:07.982 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive /Users/shikloshi/Installed/apache-tomcat-8.0.24/webapps/lit-2.war has finished in 1,763 ms
```

But when creating request to the server it result in this stack trace:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.getFirstTypeArgument(Ljava/lang/reflect/Type;)Ljava/lang/reflect/Type;
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.getInjectionResolverType(Utilities.java:497)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.checkConfiguration(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1589)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.addConfiguration(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1964)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.DynamicConfigurationImpl.commit(DynamicConfigurationImpl.java:245)
    org.jvnet.hk2.external.generator.ServiceLocatorGeneratorImpl.initialize(ServiceLocatorGeneratorImpl.java:88)
    org.jvnet.hk2.external.generator.ServiceLocatorGeneratorImpl.create(ServiceLocatorGeneratorImpl.java:98)
    org.glassfish.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorFactoryImpl.internalCreate(ServiceLocatorFactoryImpl.java:270)
    org.glassfish.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorFactoryImpl.create(ServiceLocatorFactoryImpl.java:230)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections._createLocator(Injections.java:138)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.createLocator(Injections.java:123)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:308)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:336)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:170)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:358)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1527)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1484)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My web.xml look like this:

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" version="2.5"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>lit-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>com.lit.providers.application.LitApplication</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.lit.providers</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>lit-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Relevant parts of my pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <org.glassfish.jersey>2.16</org.glassfish.jersey>
    <com.fasterxml.jackson>2.5.1</com.fasterxml.jackson>
</properties>

<artifactId>resources</artifactId>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lit.server</groupId>
        <artifactId>common</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
        <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${org.glassfish.jersey}</version>
        <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
        <version>${com.fasterxml.jackson}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>${com.fasterxml.jackson}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${com.fasterxml.jackson}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-module-jaxb-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>${com.fasterxml.jackson}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

When running this on Glassfish it worked fine.

I'm using Java 8 ant Tomcat 8.

What should I do to make my app to work on tomcat?

Comment: What is `com.lit.server`? Is it possible it is pulling in conflicting versions of HK2? Or maybe there are some dependencies you are not showing us. The error is a conflict in HK2 versions you are using. From that you have provided, we can't tell where the conflict is from, as the only thing that depends on HK2 is `jersey-container-servlet`. So this alone would not cause conflict. Conflict would be caused by something else you are not showing us, pulling in a different version of HK2, then what that version of `jersey-container-servlet` pulls in.

Comment: This was caused indeed because of a Spring dependency coming from com.lit.server:common. Thanks.